# Scheduled daily Excel 2013 exports (SSAS data source)

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export, ssas, pivot-table

On a daily basis we need to export Excel sheets (showing tables + charts) with then current SSAS data and copy the sheets into specific SharePoint document folders. I guess moving the sheets to SharePoint is the smaller task, since the folder can be used like a windows directory. I am uncertain about how to do the rest. I considered:

1) SSRS, schedule the export via Server Agent somehow (I guess this is possible since reports can be exported to Excel so the automated export is probably doable without jumping through too many loops).

2) Design the report in Excel instead (with pivot tables + charts), put this as a template into a Sharepoint library and somehow make the sheet update from the Data Source and export it into a static (not connected) sheet on a daily basis.

While I am quiet sure that 1) is doable I am totally unsure about 2), but 2) has the valuable benefit that the domain expert can make up the sheet without having to install and mess with the Report Designer.

I am thankful for any comment about approach 1 or 2 or any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with your option 1, consider setting up an email enabled SharePoint list and setting up a subscription in SSRS to email the Excel reports to that list.

For the email enabled list see
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/add-content-to-sites-by-sending-e-mail-HA010086730.aspx

For the SSRS subscription see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx

It does have the drawback that your subject matter experts might have to learn ReportBuilder, but if they can learn Excel then ReportBuilder shouldn't be too much of a stretch. If you do get option 2 working, though, post back, it sounds interesting.